# Add onClick function to ListItem with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I’m dynamically building a UniformList, with dynamic ListItems, using jQuery. All the elements are being built and displayed properly (using absolute positioning in CSS) on the page.

Edit: The following code is not from my OP. It has been edited to incorporate suggestions provided in the comments below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #container {
                position:relative;
                z-index:-1;
            }

            #myDisplay {
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                left: 100px;
                width: 400px;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: grey;
                z-index:-1;
            }

            #position_1 {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50px;
                left: 100px;
                color: black;
                z-index:1;
            }

            #fieldList {
                // placeholder
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function positionElement() {
                var list = $('<ul id="fieldList">');
                var firstItem = $('<li id="position_1">').text('test');

                // add item to list
                list.append(firstItem);
                list.append('</li>');
                // add more items...
                list.append('</ul>');

                // add list to div
                $('#myDisplay').append(list);

                // added classes to elements
                ('#fieldList').addClass('fieldList');
                ('#position_1').addClass('position_1');

                // add event listener to LIs
                $('ul.fieldList li').click(function(e) {
                    var $target = $(e.target);
                    if($target.is('li')) {
                        alert('test');
                    }
                }); 
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                positionElement();
            });
        </script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" class="container">
            <div id="myDisplay" class="myDisplay"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A couple off-topic notes. 1) Why not add .fieldList in the first statement's HTML? 2) Your `$target` var and your `if` statement are pointless considering your click function's selector.

Comment: @isherwood - There's no guarantee that the event.target is the same element bound in the selector, it could be a nested element inside the LI

Comment: Fair enough, but I see no indication of that being a concern. Maybe with more code revealed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you are appending the `<ul>` and `<li>` elements means that you end up with an empty `<ul>` and then `<li>` items are appended straight to the `#myDisplay` below. In order for your `$('ul.fieldList li')` search to turn up any elements you need the `<li>` to be within the `<ul>` parent element.

i.e. you end up with

```
<div id="myDisplay">
    <ul id="fieldList" class="fieldList"></ul>
    <li id="position_1" class="position_1"></li>
</div>
```

When I assume what you want is

```
<div id="myDisplay">
    <ul id="fieldList" class="fieldList">
        <li id="position_1" class="position_1"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So maybe something like this for the list creation:

```
var list = $('<ul>');
var firstItem = $('<li>').text("foo").addClass("bar");
list.append(firstItem);
// append more items...    
$('#myDisplay').append(list);
```

Comment: Good catch -- along the same lines of the reply below. I did make this change, to append the ListItem(s) to the UniformList. However, the onclick still isn't working. After making this change, I tried the suggestions to building the click function below.

Comment: Are you attaching the event listeners after the list has been created? Running the code when the dom has been loaded?

Here's a fiddle that works for me (Chrome, OsX 10.9)
http://jsfiddle.net/npHVf/

Comment: Yes, I am now attaching the event listeners after the list has been created and appended to the div. I just coded a sample page with the latest comments people have provided incorporated. I'll post it. Thanks again.

Comment: That fiddle was perfect. It's working now. Thanks much.

Comment: Good to hear. Seeing your edits above, I thought it might help to know that you don't have to append the closing tags of the elements, jQuery does that for you. See
[`jQuery( html [, ownerDocument ] )`documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) for details

Comment: Thanks, I took them out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click','ul.fieldList li',function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if($target.is('li')) {
        alert('test');
    }
});
```

You list item are dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector in the third line is wrong. Change

```
$('#myDisplay').append('<li id="position_1"></li>');
```

to

```
$('#fieldList').append('<li id="position_1"></li>');
```